# AchartEngine load values from db takes for ever

Tags: android, sqlite, achartengine

Goodevening,
i am developing an android application and i am using achartengine to graph values that i retrieve after quering to an sqlite database. If the values are from 0 to 1000 then i get a loading icon and after 10 secs, the most, i get the graph i need. If the values are more than 1000 and if i have multiline plot then i get a load icon that never leaves. The code i use is listed below. Am i doing anything wrong? I used the sample code from achartengine to make my own code.

Code:

```
    public void createGraph(Context ctx){
    // x data
    dateList = DateDataReturn(ctx , table, accessPointList_Filtered);
    Log.d(TAG,"dateList len:" + String.valueOf(dateList.size()));
    // y data
    dataList = yDataReturn(ctx, column, table, accessPointList_Filtered);
    Log.d(TAG, "dataList len:" + String.valueOf(dataList.size()));
    // y axis title
    yaxis = yAxisReturn(column);
    // lines titles
    titles = titleReturn(ctx, column, accessPointList_Filtered);
    Log.d(TAG,"titles length:" + String.valueOf(titles.length));
    // line colors
    colors = retColor(ctx, table, accessPointList_Filtered);
    Log.d(TAG,"colors length:" + String.valueOf(colors.length));
    // line point styles
    styles = retPointStyle(ctx, table, accessPointList_Filtered);
    Log.d(TAG,"style length:" + String.valueOf(styles.length));
    // x axis min value
    xmin = dateList.get(0)[0].getTime();
    Log.d(TAG, "1");
    // x axis max value
    xmax = dateList.get(0)[dateList.get(0).length - 1].getTime();
    Log.d(TAG, "2");
    // Create the renderer
    renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    // Create the dataset
    dataset = buildDateDataset(titles, dateList, dataList);
    Log.d(TAG, "3");
    for (int i = 0; i < renderer.getSeriesRendererCount(); i++) {
        ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }

    setChartSettings(renderer, // POINTS
            "Interface Monitoring", // PLOT LABEL
            "Time", // X LABEL
            yAxisTitleReturn(column), // Y LABEL
            xmin, 
            xmax, 
            yaxis[0], // Y AXIS START VALUE
            yaxis[1], // Y AXIS FINISH VALUE
            Color.LTGRAY, // AXIS COLOR
            Color.LTGRAY); // LABELS COLOR

    renderer.setXLabels(10);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
}


/**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @return GraphicalView, returns the view
 */
public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {
    return (GraphicalView)ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset, renderer, "h:mm:ss a");   
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you expect to have a lot of values added to the chart, you have to reduce the level of detail. This is because most of the time is spent on rendering, so this is where you can improve things:

- Disable antialiasing `renderer.setAntialiasing(false);`
- Don't use `PointStyle`s

Other suggestions:

- Add only data that is to be displayed into the model. How does a chart with so many points look like?

Also, the 1.1.0 version has a set of performance improvements included. You can download this version [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).